# iOS DidMoveToWindow Infinite Loop

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was looking into iOS NUI Framework source code. I spotted the following line of codes but I couldn't figured out how it worked

```
- (void)override_didMoveToWindow
{
    if (!self.isNUIApplied) {
        [self applyNUI];
    }
    [self override_didMoveToWindow];
}
```

Just to be clear, they swizzled out the original implementation of DidMoveToWindow with this method in order to apply the class/style at run time. What confused me was that the function above never caused any infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help: http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling

The swizzled method is actually exchanged with the original. So when the original method is called the swizzled method has already exchanged the implementation. And calling the "swizzled method" override_didMoveToWindow method will call the original function.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the line

**//[self override_didMoveToWindow];**

works for me

Comment: it's works !  iOS 15.1  Xcode 13.1  NUI = 0.5.5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not a loop because it appears the author assumes that `[self applyNUI]` always changes the state so that `self.isNUIApplied` becomes == YES

Comment: But once it got out of that conditional statement, it will call itself again which will cause a loop. I set a breakpoint and it did indeed got out of that conditional statement and hit [self override_didMoveToWindow] but it doesn't call itself again.